# In MySQL Apply a function to a hardcoded list of values

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to select a list of rows that don't actually exist (which I hardcode in the query), to be able to manipulate them with a function. Something like

`SELECT VALUES(1,2,3,4) AS col)`

My intent is to use this is a where clause or join, along the lines of

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 IN (SELECT CONCAT(col,"%") FROM (SELECT VALUES(1,2,3,4) AS col))`

Is something like this possible in MySQL? I've scoured the manual, and haven't been able to work out a way to do do this. I would also like to avoid something like

`SELECT 1 AS col1
    UNION ALL SELECT 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 4;`

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot avoid it. You can shorten it in specific cases, e.g. to get the rows 1..100, you can `cross join` two selects of the rows 1..10 (created by a `union`) (or more joins of smaller sets), but that's it.